# Question related to prepaid debit card applications

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where can I ask the following question: *Are there e-commerces or online businesses that accept credit cards but **do not** accept prepaid debit cards?* I am talking about general-purpose prepaid debit cards branded VISA, MasterCard, or a similar widely accepted franchise.

This question is part of my analysis of a prepaid card issuance project. Other related questions are, Should I consider as potential transactions for my prepaid debit card all those that a credit card can do? Should I exclude from my potential market certain merchants or transactions?

For instance, although Spotify publicly says [they accept al prepaid debit cards](https://support.spotify.com/us/article/Payment-Methods/), some users and even administrators [state the contrary](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Accounts/Does-Spotify-Accept-Prepaid-Debit-Cards/td-p/348446).

**Edit:** Thanks to [S. L. Barth](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/168333/s-l-barth), I posted the following question on Startups: *"[Reasons *not* to accept prepaid cards on your store](https://startups.stackexchange.com/questions/13591/reasons-not-to-accept-prepaid-cards-on-your-store)"*

Comment: Are you asking from the point of view of an individual using the cards or as a business accepting them?

Comment: @Catija, I am asking from the point of view of the business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are there e-commerces or online businesses that accept credit cards but **do not** accept prepaid debit cards?

This question does not fit the Stack Exchange model very well. There might be, but they might change their policy at any time. The answer, whatever it is, is not going to be of long-term value.

A better question would be if there was a reason for an online venture to not accept prepaid debit cards. Or, what the risks are for an online venture to accept them.
That might be on-topic on one of our business/financial sites; [Startups](https://startups.stackexchange.com) comes to mind. However, I am not active there myself, so I cannot say this for certain; check their [Help Center](https://startups.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to determine this for yourself.

> Should I consider as potential transactions for my prepaid debit card all those that a credit card can do?

This sounds like a good question for Stack Exchange; one to which the answer can be supported with verifiable facts. It's probably a good fit for one of our business/financial sites.

> Should I exclude from my potential market certain merchants or transactions?

This question is not a good fit for Stack Exchange; naming specific merchants is too close to bad-mouthing specific people or organisations, and could bring trouble to the answerer.
Excluding specific types of transactions, again, might be a good question for our business/financial sites.

Comment: Thank you Barth! That is a very good answer. I concurr with you: I'll post the *"Should I consider as potential transactions for my prepaid debit card all those that a credit card can do?"* question in Startups. Thanks!

Comment: @PabloMarambio You're welcome! Be sure to include some prior research into your question when you post there. Or at least prior thinking about the problem. You probably know how critical people on SE can be, showing prior research goes a long way to getting upvotes (or at least avoiding downvotes).

Comment: @PabloMarambio To go even further, you may want to instead research whether or not prepaid cards are even functionally different than any other credit or debit card that exists. It's quite possible merchants don't have a choice because they aren't identified in any way that would distinguish them from any other card (after all, they *are* just a card number with expiration date like anything else) and that users "having problems" just aren't using them properly (e.g. didn't activate it first or don't have enough funds left to cover the charge).